# Windows 10 installer booting error

Tags: windows-error-reporting

This is the error i am getting. I used a 32bit win 10 ISO and got this message. Will this be resolved if i use a 64bit win10 ISO?

[image]

Comment: Is this an upgrade? or a clean install?

Comment: I tried to upgrade my 32bit windows 10 64bit, first i had another error and i deleted all my drives, then i tried using 32bit installer and it it showing this booting error

Comment: You cannot "cross-grade" 32 to 64-bit or vice versa. You must wipe completely & start afresh to switch from one to the other.

Comment: @OLDMAN Download Windows ISO from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB from the ISO, ensuring CSM [Legacy] Mode is disabled within the UEFI firmware prior to booting it, as either the bootable USB wasn't correctly created or CSM Mode is enabled _(CSM Mode should never be enabled, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017, emulating BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit env & will cause performance degradation (boot times increase, GPT can't be used, etc.)_

Comment: So should i use 32bit win10 iso or 64bit iso

Comment: If you want to stick with UEFI booting, you'll need 64-bit iso. 32-bit Windows can only be used on 32-bit UEFI or via CSM / legacy booting on 64-bit UEFI.

Comment: Hey can u tell me how to boot a 32bit setup ( iso from official site 32bit) on a pc thats saying "bootx64.efi not found"

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to use 32bit iso to upgrade via CSM/ legacy on 64bit UEFI

Comment: @OLDMAN You should install the 64bit edition

Comment: Okay, but now i have another issue... 
 
 https://superuser.com/q/1659024/1446965

Answer (score 0):

In the error the system says that it uses a 64-bit UEFI
(Unified Extensible Firmware Interface, something like the BIOS)

Try to boot a 64 bit ISO.

Comment: While it doesn't make sense to install any 32bit OS, x64 UEFI firmware is backward compatible with 32bit OSes.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: @JW0914 Except you can't load the 32-bit UEFI variant of Windows Boot Manager with 64-bit UEFI and you can neither use that variant of WBM to load a 64-bit Windows installation.

Comment: But i think my pc does not support 64 bit

Comment: @TomYan I'm unsure why the clarification was needed since that wasn't the topic or point of my comment, which was simply to relay that a 32bit OS can be used on a motherboard with 64bit UEFI firmware _(there was no reason to cover EFI boot vs CSM [Legacy] Mode using MBR)_

Comment: What should i do?... how can i boot a 32bit setup on a pc thats saying "bootx64.efi not found"

Comment: Pls tell me whether i should boot a 64bit win10 or 32bit win10?????

Comment: @JW0914 Not all UEFI comes with CSM. In fact, I'm more unsure what's the point of pointing out a 64-bit UEFI *might* be able to boot *some* 32-bit OSes / bootloader. Isn't that even more irrelevant to the OP than my comment. (And why am I not surprised when that comes to you.)

Comment: This error is coming when i m trying to boot a 32bit win10 setup... whereas when i tryto boot a 64bit win 10, the page opens up but then the  problem occurs, i m unable to click the "next" button in the partition oage

Comment: Hey, i m now trying to make another bootable usb using 64bit iso for windows 10 using rufus... so can someone tell me what all options should i click?