# Windows 10 installer drive error

Tags: windows-error-reporting

Error 0x80300024

[image: Error 0x80300024]

I am unable to click the next button

Comment: It shows error code 0x80300024

Comment: Mr @jitter is on to something here.. is this a FRESH INSTALL?  Are you trying to preserve something?  Is this a pre-install from an OEM that you are installing over?  We don't know what the drive types are or why there is already a ton of data on drive0.  The partitions look poorly allocated to begin with.  We need drive types of drive0 and drive1, we need to know the context of why you are installing.  This will help us give you the optimal answer.

Comment: I was trying to upgrade my 32bit pc to 64 bit

Comment: Do you happen to know what CPU your PC has?

Comment: Means? What should i  check

Comment: We super geeks need more specs so we can debate your best options.  What amount of ram?  what proc?  what are the drive types?  Also.. I am bouncing around here from the coffee but all of these other people helping are awesome and I mean no offense to any of them.

Comment: And.. as I point out, 64 IS NOT BETTER than 32.  It depends on what you plan on doing.  Don't let the numbers fool you.

Comment: My ram is 2gb, and my processor showed "32bitos×64based processor" this is the reason why i tried to make my pc 64bit.... now i regret that decision.... my pc is not opening and the next button in the setup from the usb is not working tooo..... what to do now

Comment: Any idea????????

Comment: 2gb? DO NOT attempt to install a 64bit OS.  It will do you ZERO good.. in fact, it will take you the other way.  Also.. like I said, 64 bit will buy you very little anyway.  64bit was created to be able to address HUGE numbers.  HUGE amounts of memory or address space like a database might need.  It gets more complicate than that.. but that is the basic way you might think of it.  Enjoy what you have mr. oldman.  I too have a 2gb machine as a spare and it runs 32bit OS just fine.

Comment: The problem now is when i try to boot the 32bit installer (iso of 32bit win10 from official site) there is an error coming which is bootx64.efi not found.... so this means my pc only allows 64 bit installers....is it?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas If the PC comes with a 64-bit UEFI with no CSM, he doesn't really have a choice.

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: Will this work with a windows 8 iso? Which one should i download 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: `What to do now?` ..you should look at the @TomYan answer below.  I didn't consider 64bit UEFI firmware.  *Normally* what I said about 64bit on 2gb would be true.. but what TomYan said is also true.

Comment: You have yet to provide specs.  Is this a prebuilt pc?  If so, please tell us which one.  If not, we need the model of motherboard and cpu to help you better.

Comment: Check this question of mine 
 https://superuser.com/q/1658986/1446965

Comment: I m making another bootable usb using rufus of windows 10 64bit... so can someone tell me what all options should i check .... send a photo or somethimg

Answer (score 0):

Click `Drive 1 Unallocated Space` first.

Comment: This is not wrong @TomYan but this might not be the best advice.  To proceed.. sure, optimal, it depends on the drive types.  What is wrong with drive0?  Is that SSD while 1 is HDD?  Why is all of that space taken up on drive0 with a fresh install.  This answer is too simple to give the best advice.

Comment: Tried still no....

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: Any idea?......

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Obviously you didn't notice the label `Backup` of `Drive 0 Partition 1`...

Comment: @OLDMAN Well, you'll have to show cause of the potential *new* problem (Click on `(Show details)` *after* `Drive 1` is selected / highlighted.)

Comment: It shows windows cant be installed on this drive and an error code"0x80300024"

Comment: It shows windows cant be installed on this drive and an error code"0x80300024"

Answer (score 0):

The disk you selected (Drive 0) isn't big enough to install Windows on. Try picking one of the other ones. If it still gives you the same error, it means your PC doesn't meet the minimum specs for Windows. You can check said minimum spec requirements here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications

Comment: So are u saying i should use a 32bit iso for setup

Comment: No, I said to pick one of the other drives. You should never use a 32 bit installer unless your PC isn't 64 bit.

Comment: My pc is 32bit.... i tried to make it 64 bit ... and next button is not working.... so i removed the USB and now the pc is not opening it is now showing error code 0xc0000225

Comment: I disagree @jitter, sometimes.. a 32bit install is optimal depending on how the machine will be used.  I DO AGREE that your advice is sound but "should never use" is [silly](http://www.iinuu.eu/en/it-guru/windows-7-32-vs-64-bit-performance-benchmark).  It isn't black and white or "64 is better than 32".  Why persay to do think that visual studio is still a 32bit application?

Comment: My pc does not open.

Comment: @OLDMAN Press F8 on the screen with the "0xc0000225" error and try to find a button that says something along the lines of "Factory reset". If F8 doesn't do anything, you need to use the recovery tools on your USB.

Comment: Tried, f8 is not working

Comment: Plug the USB back in, and instead of pressing "Install now", there should be a "Repair now" button in the bottom left. Press that.

Comment: Tried still not working, i think the problem is that i deleted all partitions.....

Comment: Just try "install now" instead then. Try picking the "Drive 1 unallocated space" when it asks you to select a drive to install to.

Comment: Tried, still i m unable to click next....its saying .Error 0x80300024

Comment: Hallo...........

Comment: I'd say your best bet right now would be to contact your PC manufacturers, or Microsoft support. They would be able to help you more in depth then we can.

Comment: Okay, thanks.....

Comment: If i delete all drives from the above pic, will i be able to click next?

Comment: @OLDMAN Better not delete your `Backup` unless you don't really care about it

Comment: I deleted all drives, (also i backed up all my  data on my hard disk.....) now i m unable to click "next" button.... Btw, will the windows 8 32bit boot up if i try?