# installing 32bit windows 10 setup on 64bit uefi

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I tried to upgrade a 32bit windows 10 to 64bit windows 10 and it got stuck at the partitions window. I deleted all partitions and i am unable to click "next" button. So when i put a 32bit installer USB, the error comes: "`bootx64.efi` not found".!

[image: the image of the state when i m unable to click "next" button.(this happens when i use 64bit installation usb of windows 10)][image]

Comment: Pls tell me how to install a 32bit windows 10 iso on a 64bit UEFI

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. Please clarify what you actually want to do: Remove Windows 10 64-bit and install Windows 10 32-bit? OR remove Windows 10 32-bit and install Windows 10 64-bit? // 32-bit Windows does not support 64-bit UEFI. Did you enable legacy booting (sometimes called “CSM”) yet?

Comment: My pc was 32bit windows 10, i tried to upgrade it to 64 bit....

Comment: It all went correctly until i reached the partition/ drive selection window... there i was unable to click the next button.....

Comment: So i removed that usb and used a 32bit win10 usb...this time i get the error bootx64.efi not found

Comment: This question has a history - https://superuser.com/questions/1658986/windows-10-installer-booting-error and  https://superuser.com/questions/1659024/windows-10-installer-drive-error

Comment: Ya, i did that q

Comment: I need to know how i can use 32bit windows 10 installer (extracted iso in usb) to upgrade a 64bit UEFI......

Comment: Windows needs a fair bit of space in order to be installed. The first partition of 16 mb of unallocated space is just not enough. The bottom one is however. So if you click that unallocated space, the setup screen will recognize that it can install, and the next button can be clicked. There's also the yellow exclaimation mark with "Windows cannot install to this drive, click here why" which if you clicked would tell you it needs a minimum of 10 GB or something. 10 GB is 10.000 MB.

Comment: So if i delete all the partitions, will i be able to click next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 installer drive error](https://superuser.com/questions/1659024/windows-10-installer-drive-error)

Comment: @OLDMAN you just need to click the bottom line first, then you can click next.

Comment: I want to find a way to boot the 32bit windows 10 installer....(Now its saying bootx64.efi not found) so if anyone knows a way please let me know

Comment: The bootloader was in the first partition of 16 MB that you deleted. But selecting the 2nd disk should still recreate it without creating any partition.

Comment: Ok i will try, but now i only have a 32bit version of installer on the usb so is there anyway i could use it to upgrade?

Comment: Hey, i m now trying to make another bootable usb using 64bit iso for windows 10 using rufus... so can someone tell me what all options should i click?

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs a fair bit of space in order to be installed. The first partition of 16 mb of unallocated space is just not enough. The bottom one is however. So if you click that unallocated space, the setup screen will recognize that it can install, and the next button can be clicked.

There's also the yellow exclaimation mark with "Windows cannot install to this drive, click here why" which if you clicked would tell you it needs a minimum of 30 GB. 10 GB is 10.000 MB.

Comment: Windows 10 requires ~30GB for the OS partition, as Microsoft made the change to Windows 10 a few years back to ensure the OS partition was guaranteed enough free space for updates [~7GB IIRC]. IIRC, there is a workaround, but I may be misremembering _(the size constraint often comes up with eMMC devices)_

Comment: @JW0914 thanks. I've edited it.